# Why is my public variable being shown as " 'this' is not available"?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to populate a listview with data from a database but it won't allow me to assign a string variable.

i have read some other articles on this but i cannot for the life of me figure out why my variable is shown as " 'this' is not available " When i use the debugger.

```
public class InventoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private RecyclerView varRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter varAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager varLayoutManager;

private static String URL_FindInventory = "MyPHPFile";

//IM TRYING TO SET THESE TWO VARIABLES
public String itemOneName, itemOneEffect;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventory);

    String characterID = getIntent().getStringExtra("characterID");

    ArrayList<LayoutItem> inventoryList = new ArrayList<>();

    FindInventory(characterID);

    inventoryList.add(new LayoutItem(R.drawable.ic_add_circle, itemOneName, itemOneEffect));
    inventoryList.add(new LayoutItem(R.drawable.ic_add_circle, "Item Two Name", "Item Two's Effect"));

    varRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    varRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    varLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    varAdapter = new LayoutAdapter(inventoryList);

    varRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(varLayoutManager);
    varRecyclerView.setAdapter(varAdapter);
}


private void FindInventory(final String characterID)
{
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_FindInventory,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                        String result = jsonObject.getString("result");

                        if (result != null)
                        {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");

                            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

           //IM TRYING TO USE THESE TWO VARIABLES TO SET THE PUBLIC ONES.
                                String itemName = object.getString("Name").trim(); // this has a value of "Cap of Thinking"
                                String itemEffect = object.getString("Effect").trim(); // this has a value of "Helps the user to think +2 Intelligence"

                                itemOneName = itemName;  // THIS IS SHOWN AS "ItemOneName = 'this' is not available "
                                itemOneEffect = itemEffect; // THIS IS SHOWN AS "ItemOneEffect = 'this' is not available "

                            }

                        }
                        else if ((result.equals("error")))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(InventoryActivity.this, "Cannot find Inventory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(InventoryActivity.this, "Exception Error " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(InventoryActivity.this, "Error " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("characterid", characterID);

            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

When I'm trying to set the value of the 2 public strings they are being set as null, I can't for the life of me figure out why it won't allow me to set there value to the variables I read from the JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are null because your web request happens after you added the items to the lists.

Make `inventoryList` a field and remove the two string fields you're trying to set

Move the two `inventoryList.add` methods into the onResponse, then you need to notify the RecyclerView adapter that new data needs to be displayed

Comment: it seems so obvious now haha feel like an absolute "Bad Word"... Thank you very much that fixed it straight away. I've been on this all day haha

Comment: Welcome. Never hurts to add excessive logging statements

Answer (score 0):

The reason they are null is because when the compiler executes below two lines(let's call it line 1 and line 2):

```
FindInventory(characterID);//line 1

inventoryList.add(new LayoutItem(R.drawable.ic_add_circle, itemOneName, itemOneEffect));//line 2
```

-At line 1, the method gets executed asynchronously(means that it will not block the execution of line 2, line 2 will be executed either after or before line 1).  This causes the variables itemOneName and itemOneEffect to be null, since line 2 was executed before line 1, remember line 1 and line 2 are being executed in parallel or same time.

To fix this:

-You have to do below:

```
inventoryList.add(new LayoutItem(R.drawable.ic_add_circle, itemOneName, itemOneEffect));
inventoryList.add(new LayoutItem(R.drawable.ic_add_circle, "Item Two Name", "Item Two's Effect"));

...and other dependencies
```

After you invoke these lines within onResponse():

```
String itemName = object.getString("Name").trim(); // this has a value of "Cap of Thinking"
String itemEffect = object.getString("Effect").trim();
```